# Django: How to check if user has already voted on ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

```
    class Punch(models.Model):
        ring            = models.ForeignKey(Ring)
        voters           = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    class Ring(models.Model):
        category        = xxxx
```

I have this class with a ManyToManyField.

Each user should be able to vote only once for each punch.
Now I need to know if a user has already voted for a particular punch.

How would I do that?

```
punch.voters.filter(??? = request.user)
```

Reading the documentation I came up with this:

```
voters = get_user_model().objects.filter(punch__voters=request.user)
```

but this gives me the total number of times a user has voted for all punches. But I am interested in one particular punch only, to see if he has voted for that.

I am still struggling to solve this.
Thanks for help

Comment: Why is it `votes` and not `voters`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
punch.voters.filter(pk=request.user.pk)
```

You can also replace the `filter` with a `try-expect` wrapped `get`

Comment: Superb. With a small modification it works: `punch.voters.filter(pk=user.pk)`  Thanks

Comment: that would be an interesting alternative. Wouldnt throwing an expect more expensive than filter though?

Answer (score 2):

Many-to-many relationships can be queried using lookups [across relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).